# Java - remove new-lines from byte array

Tags: java

so I am currently trying to use this (horribly inefficient) method to remove newlines from a byte array

```
public void fixPasswords() {
    ArrayList<Byte> active = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Byte> stored = new ArrayList<>();
    for (byte b : activePassword) {
        if (b!='\n'||b!='\r') {
            active.add(b);
        }
    }
    activePassword = new byte[active.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < active.size(); i++) {
        activePassword[i] = active.get(i);
    }

    for (byte b : storedPassword) {
        if (b!='\n'||b!='\r') {
            stored.add(b);
        }
    }
    storedPassword = new byte[stored.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < stored.size(); i++) {
        storedPassword[i] = stored.get(i);
    }
    activePasswordString = new String(activePassword);
    storedPasswordString = new String(storedPassword);
    System.out.println("Active: "+activePasswordString);
    System.out.println("Stored: "+storedPasswordString);
}
```

However, it is not removing newlines

```
Active: fK��f3�Nc1L�2*j�JQ��b�@|�`
Stored: >K�U�0p
uvn��B�
```

stored password still seems to keep newlines, how would I go about detecting newlines in a byte array and removing them?

Comment: You should not be modifying text as a byte array. Use `String` or `char[]`.

Comment: Note that you are comparing `byte` to `\n` or `\r`. A byte is always one byte long (8 bit), but text (depending on the encoding) can be longer. Common encodings like UTF-8 have variable byte length. Therefore you should parse your bytes to regular text using the encoding and then compare text to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the && (and) operator, not the || (or) operator.

Your code:

```
if (b!='\n'||b!='\r')
```

Try this instead:

```
if (b!='\n'&&b!='\r')
```

The *or* operator only requires one of the conditions to evaluate to `true` for it to be `true`. Even if `b` does equal `'\n'`, it will be true that `b!='\r'`, and vice versa. So the *or* expression will always evaluate to true, and you will add every character from the byte array.

Comment: Can you highlight the problem with the first comparison? Like *always `true` because of this and that*.

Comment: No I understand, thank you, I blanked, my statemnt will always return true because it can never be both a \r and \n at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

hm, how about something like that:

```
public void fixPasswords() {

    byte[] activePassword = "fK��\u000Ef3�Nc1\fL�2*j�JQ��b�@|�`\r".getBytes();
    byte[] storedPassword = ">K�U�0p\nuvn��B�".getBytes();


    String activePasswordString = parsePassword(activePassword);
    String storedPasswordString = parsePassword(storedPassword);
    System.out.println("Active: "+activePasswordString);
    System.out.println("Stored: "+storedPasswordString);
}

private String parsePassword(byte[] password){
    return  new String(password).replaceAll("[\\n\\r]", "");
}
```